# PIL Image getpixel TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to use the `getpixel((w,h))` method of `PIL.Image` but we processing image this give a

`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Error, it seems that method don't return a three elements tuple, have tried with both png file and jpg file same result, what happend?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PIL import Image

def makeIndex():
    pic = Image.open('lines.jpg')
    width = pic.width
    height = pic.height
    for w in range(0, width):
        for h in range(0, height):
            r,g,b= pic.getpixel((w,h))
            print (r,g,b)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    makeIndex()

# vim:ai:et:sts=4:sw=4:
```

### EDIT

as mentioned by the comment this time I chose another png file to do the test and do a `convert('RGB')` before processing

```
    pic = Image.open('stencil.png').convert('RGB')
    width = pic.width
    height = pic.height
    for w in range(0, width):
        for h in range(0, height):
            r,g,b= pic.getpixel((w,h))
            print (w,h), (r,g,b)
```

And this give a result of

```
(106, 988) (141, 60, 146)
(106, 989) (141, 60, 146)
(106, 990) (141, 60, 146)
(106, 991) (141, 60, 146)
(106, 992) (130, 36, 36)
(106, 993) (130, 36, 36)
(106, 994) (130, 36, 36)
(106, 995) (130, 36, 36)
(106, 996) (130, 36, 36)
(106, 997) (130, 36, 36)
(106, 998) (130, 36, 36)
(106, 999) (130, 36, 36)
```

And each has different r,g,b value

So what does this `layer` things really mean?

[image]

Comment: It seems your image has just one layer which means it is a grey image.

Comment: You probably have an indexed image. Try `pic = Image.open('lines.jpg').convert('RGB')`

Comment: What they said. `r,g,b= pic.getpixel((w,h))` _does_ work if the image really has 3 layers. BTW, processing a whole image using `Image.getpixel` and `Image.putpixel` is _really_ slow ; those methods should really only be used to work on a small number of isolated pixels.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to find all the unique colors in your image file, if so, you can use `colors = set(Image.open(filename).getdata())`. If it's a palette-mapped image, you'll need to convert it first to RGB: `set(Image.open(filename).convert('RGB').getdata())`; it's safe to do `.convert('RGB')` on an image that's already in RGB mode.

Comment: The PIL Image object of an RGB image has 3 layers, one for each color channel. So there's a red layer, a green layer, and a blue layer. If you want, you can perform various image processing operations on each layer separately.

Comment: @PM2Ring but since what I work on is a colored image instead of a gray image so it is wired that it only has one layer

Comment: PNG has various ways to represent images. If the image only has a small number of colors (≤256) it can store the image in palette-mapped format. So each number in the layer is an index into the palette, which is an array of colors. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color